# Fatal error: Invalid state: A login callback was received, but no login request was sent

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

This error occurs when trying to **SignIn with Apple** with **Swift** :

> Fatal error: Invalid state: A login callback was received, but no login request was sent

I followed this [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/apple?authuser=0) by Firebase. The only thing I had to do different is:

```
let credential = OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: "apple.com", idToken: idTokenString, rawNonce: nonce, accessToken: nil)
```

instead of

```
let credential = OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: "apple.com",
                                            IDToken: idTokenString,
                                            rawNonce: nonce)
```

as the code form the documentation gives an error.

Here is my method:

```
func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
  if let appleIDCredential = authorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential {
    guard let nonce = currentNonce else {
      fatalError("Invalid state: A login callback was received, but no login request was sent.")
    }
    guard let appleIDToken = appleIDCredential.identityToken else {
      print("Unable to fetch identity token")
      return
    }
    guard let idTokenString = String(data: appleIDToken, encoding: .utf8) else {
      print("Unable to serialize token string from data: \(appleIDToken.debugDescription)")
      return
    }
//        // Initialize a Firebase credential.
//        let credential = OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: "apple.com",
//                                                  IDToken: idTokenString,
//                                                  rawNonce: nonce)


 let credential = OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: "apple.com", idToken: idTokenString, rawNonce: nonce, accessToken: nil)

    // Sign in with Firebase.
    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
        if (error != nil) {
        // Error. If error.code == .MissingOrInvalidNonce, make sure
        // you're sending the SHA256-hashed nonce as a hex string with
        // your request to Apple.
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        return
      }
      // User is signed in to Firebase with Apple.
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my [Git-Project](https://github.com/DieGlueckswurst/Wishlist). To reproduce the error just run the app and tap on the `appleButton`.

Comment: Remove `accessToken`.

Comment: that doesn't change anything

Comment: Can you add complete code?

Comment: added my git repo to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code functions "startSignInWithAppleFlow" and "sha256" are written inside "randomNonceString".

corrected version

```
private func randomNonceString(length: Int = 32) -> String {
        precondition(length > 0)
        let charset: Array<Character> =
            Array("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-._")
        var result = ""
        var remainingLength = length

        while remainingLength > 0 {
            let randoms: [UInt8] = (0 ..< 16).map { _ in
                var random: UInt8 = 0
                let errorCode = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 1, &random)
                if errorCode != errSecSuccess {
                    fatalError("Unable to generate nonce. SecRandomCopyBytes failed with OSStatus \(errorCode)")
                }
                return random
            }

            randoms.forEach { random in
                if remainingLength == 0 {
                    return
                }

                if random < charset.count {
                    result.append(charset[Int(random)])
                    remainingLength -= 1
                }
            }
        }
        return result
    }



    @available(iOS 13, *)
    func startSignInWithAppleFlow() {
        let nonce = randomNonceString()
        currentNonce = nonce
        let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
        let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
        request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
        request.nonce = sha256(nonce)

        let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
        authorizationController.delegate = self
        authorizationController.presentationContextProvider = self
        authorizationController.performRequests()
    }

    @available(iOS 13, *)
    func sha256(_ input: String) -> String {
        let inputData = Data(input.utf8)
        let hashedData = SHA256.hash(data: inputData)
        let hashString = hashedData.compactMap {
            return String(format: "%02x", $0)
        }.joined()

        return hashString
    }
```

Ans call "startSignInWithAppleFlow" from "appleButtonTapped" like this

```
@objc func appleButtonTapped(){

       startSignInWithAppleFlow()
}
```

Comment: I think that was it :) Thanks! Could you maybe have a look at my other question regarding SignInWithApple?